# Change the searchDisplayController table view style to grouped?

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uitableview

I have a `searchDisplayController` that searches a `UITableView`.

After entering the search terms, I can see another `UITableView` that contains the search results. However, I want this `UITableView` to be GROUPED, not PLAIN (like it is by default).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If - like me - you think the plain TableView was way too ugly, you can also abandon the use of SearchDisplayController.

I just:

- inserted in an empty View a **searchBar** and a **TableView** as we usually do for IBOutlet
- selected the **File's owner as delegate for both of them**.
- At the beginin the number of section is 0 ([myTab count]) then I used reloadData and this time myTab is populated by the result.
- `[self.resultTableView reloadData]`;

Here you can find all the method I used from the delegates

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIApplicationDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
    IBOutlet UITableView *resultTableView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *resultTableView;

  //For your searchBar the 2 most important methods are
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBarClicked;
- (BOOL)searchBarTextDidEndEditing;


  //For your TableView the most important methods are in my case:

    //number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
    //HEADERS
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
    //different numbers of row by section
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
    //the cells themselves
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end
```

After all, the simplest solution is often the best...

Comment: This is a great insight and really streamlined the use of a search bar in my application. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me (iOS 5.0):

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
[self.searchController setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UITableViewStyleGrouped]
        forKey:@"_searchResultsTableViewStyle"];
```

Comment: That's actually the best solution in this post. THANKS!

Comment: `_searchResultsTableViewStyle` doesn't seem to be documented... Will this pass Apple's approval ?

Comment: I used this, and my app was approved. In my opinion this should be documented by Apple.

Comment: I don't see any reason they should reject an app for doing this, but the danger is that the names change in future versions of iOS and you have to change your app to keep up.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

Create a class which extends UISearchDisplayController:

```
@interface RVSearchDisplayController : UISearchDisplayController
@end

@implementation RVSearchDisplayController

-(UITableView *) searchResultsTableView {
    [self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UITableViewStyleGrouped]
            forKey:@"_searchResultsTableViewStyle"];
    return [super searchResultsTableView];
}

@end
```

Then add a `UISearchDisplayController` to your table using IB, and change its Custom Class to `RVSearchDisplayController` in Identity Inspector.

Comment: Does that count as using a private api?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create a subclass of UISearchDisplayController and make searchResultsTableView searchable

in any .h file add:

```
@interface YourUISearchDisplayController : UISearchDisplayController {
   UITableView * searchResultsTableView;
}

@property (nonatomic) UITableView * searchResultsTableView;

@end;
```

Then just use YourUISearchDisplayController instead od UISearchDisplayController.

Note: you might have to use (nonatomic, retain), (nonatomic, assign), or (nonatomic, copy). I'm not really sure

Comment: "Then just use YourUISearchDisplayController instead of UISearchDisplayController."

So this is what I did:
myUISearchDisplayController = [[MyUISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
 self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView = myUISearchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;

But it gives me the error that "/RootViewController.m:472: error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found
"

Is there a work-around?

Comment: @David, I don't think it's possible to override properties in Objective-C,  it's only possible to override **methods**.

Comment: Yeah it looks like you're out of luck. Turns out even if you write setters for read-only properties they just keep calling themselves.

Comment: As an afterthought: you can ask apple to change it, though I don't know what the odds are there.

Comment: You could try adding a standalone method to your derived class instead of trying to override a readonly property (which you can't): `-[YourUISearchDisplayController setSearchResultsTableViewStyle:]`

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as the `searchResultsTableView` property is `readonly`.

Comment: so basically there is absolutely no way to change it to a grouped style? that's absurd that apple would refrain us from doing such a thing..

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `-searchResultsTableView` won't work, because `UISearchDisplayController` accesses its table view instance variable directly, without calling the method.

The designated initializer for `UISearchDisplayController` appears to be a private method, `-initWithSearchBar:contentsController:searchResultsTableViewStyle:`, which sets the `_searchResultsTableViewStyle` instance variable.  This instance variable is used in creating the search results table view.  The public initializer calls this method, passing `UITableViewStylePlain`.

Directly calling the private designated initializer or setting the instance variable would likely get an application rejected from the App Store, so you might instead try overriding the public initializer and calling

```
[self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UITableViewStyleGrouped]
        forKey:@"searchResultsTableViewStyle"];
```